# Why are the array indexes not being swapped?

Tags: java, arrays, object

I am trying to get an array position to be swapped and it will not work. No matter what I do, I cannot get them to be swapped, I know it has something to do with the way I have the if statement written.

Here is the code in the main :

```
  Comparable[] computerSizes = new Comparable[3];

   int a = computerSizes.length - 1;



   computerSizes[0] = new Desktop("i5","Desktop",4,1024,250); 
   computerSizes[1] = new Desktop("i3","Desktop",6,512,350); 
   computerSizes[2] = new Laptop(15.6,"i3","Laptop",4,0,750); 

   for (int i = 0; i < a;i++) {

     if(computerSizes[i].compareTo(computerSizes[i+1]) == 1){
          computerSizes[i] = computerSizes[i+1];
          computerSizes[i+1] = computerSizes[i];
        }//end if
     System.out.println(computerSizes[i]);
    }//end for
```

Here is the relevant compareTo method code:

```
 public int compareTo(Comparable c)
{   
    Computer a = (Computer)c;


     if (this.cost == a.cost)
        return 0;
     else if (this.cost > a.cost)
        return 1;
     else
        return -1;



}
```

Index at 0 is greater than index at 1 but just for clarification I will include relvant formula which is:

```
cost = 150 + 6.50 * super.ram + 0.15 * super.hdd + 0.48 * super.vRam;
```

Desktop(PROCESSOR,TYPE,RAM,VRAM,HDD SPACE): this is what the parameters mean.

Comment: Seriously? You can't swap like that!!

Comment: It mad sense at first glance. I forgot "=" is a two way street.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The lines

```
computerSizes[i] = computerSizes[i+1];
computerSizes[i+1] = computerSizes[i];
```

don't do what you expect. It first assign the value of `computerSizes[i+1]` to `computerSizes[i]`. At that moment, both are equal. Then you assign the value of `computerSizes[i]` to `computerSizes[i+1]`. At the end, both will be equal.

In order to swap the values, use a temporal variable:

```
Comparable temp = computerSizes[i];
computerSizes[i] = computerSizes[i+1];
computerSizes[i+1] = temp;
```

Comment: Unfortunately it did not solve my program, just that particular part. Apparently, the problem runs deeper than that.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Temp Comparable to do SWAP

```
  Comparable tempComparable;
  if(computerSizes[i].compareTo(computerSizes[i+1]) == 1){
          tempCoparable = computerSizes[i];
          computerSizes[i] = computerSizes[i+1];
          computerSizes[i+1] = tempComparable;
        }//end if
```

Answer (score 1):

Let us consider an array : `new int[3]{ 1, 2, 3 };`

What you are doing is:

```
a[i] = a[i+1];
a[i+1] = a[i];
```

which does (let i = 0):

```
1. {1,2,3}   
2. {2,2,3}   |a[0] i.e. 1 gets replaced by 2
3. {2,2,3}   |a[1] i.e. 2 gets replaced by 2 (though it must be replaced by 1)
```

So, there must be a way to keep a temporary variable.
Let's consider the following:

```
Computer temp = computerSizes[i];
computerSizes[i] = computerSizes[i+1];
computerSizes[i+1] = temp;
```

This will give the required result.

Answer (score 0):

As various answers say, your swap code won't work because you have no intermediate variable

```
      myarray[i] = myarray[i+1];  // both i and i+1 now refer to the same object
      myarray[i+1] = myarray[i];  // so this line has no effect
```

If your goal is to sort your objects, you can do this with `Arrays.sort()` by providing a comparator object - see the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort%28T%5B%5D,%20java.util.Comparator%29).

Answer (score 0):

Swapping code is incorrect. It should be

```
  if(computerSizes[i].compareTo(computerSizes[i+1]) == 1){
              Computer temp = computerSizes[i]
              computerSizes[i] = computerSizes[i+1];
              computerSizes[i+1] = temp ;
            }//end if
```